# comic effect of one image macro

Tags: meaning

I am not sure whether my following question belongs to this site. I want to ask you where is the point of this so called image macro with J. S. Bach.  I am probably unwitty but I am not able to figure out its comic effect.

[image: Image text "Transcribes Violin Concerto for Harpsichord - Chance for More Voices"]

Comment: Musically, violins and harpsichords can be referred to as "voices". But I've really no idea what was going through the mind of whoever produced your example. I don't know too much about musical terminology either, but my first thought is ***Transpose** violin concertos **to** harpsichord* sounds more likely, but there's no meaningful "syntax" to the words anyway. Do you even know if it came from a native speaker?

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is essentially a case of music theory jargon, which is why it doesn't seem to make sense on its face. The one thing I'm not sure about here is the usage for *for*: I'm pretty sure it's normal in music theory to talk this way, but it may be that it should be *to* as you suggested.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: no, "Transpose" has a specific meaning in Music, of changing the key. "Transcribe" is the right word. I think "for" is good as well, thugh that's not so clear-cut.

Comment: @Era: Offhand I can't think of a justifiable reason for closevoting, but I have to say that if ***I*** can't make sense of the text, it's not obvious to me how *anything* that anyone could say here would be particularly useful for someone trying to learn English. It just looks like a bunch of words to me, though from the format it's obvious *someone* thought it meant something "funny".

Comment: It's also possible that there is some missing context, e.g. from where the image was posted on a web forum or something.

Comment: Consider the word "voices". It might be a wordplay. Change in order to attract more voices (like in election )

Comment: It's an anagram for Every Stupid Fad Has its Wikipedia Page.

Comment: It may be an inside joke. Many meme making sites keep the images folks have made publically available for a while, so this may refer to something funny that happened between friends that we couldn't possibly know about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This joke depends on knowledge about music-- the joke itself isn't linguistic in nature. Basically, the joke is about J. S. Bach's tendency to use many [voices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_(music)) in his work. The idea is that instead of simply transcribing the concerto from one instrument to another, he uses it as an opportunity to add even more voices to the piece.

Comment: I can't see much point to it (and I am a musician) unless it is intended as a bit of political satire, about more voices being heard (usually, about voices of people from different communities).

Comment: @Colin: I agree that unless either this particular composer (Bach?) or musicians in general are especially keen to maximize the number of "voices" in their work (which seems unlikely), we'd have to suppose there's an allusion to *voices = (political) perspectives*. But there's still no real point, and so far as I can see nothing we can say has any real connection to "learning English".

Comment: @ColinFine I suspect that it's just not a very good joke. It's also possible that it's an *inside joke* in reference to some conversation that the creator had, e.g. complaining to a friend that some Bach piece they were studying had too many voices. (I don't know how plausible that is, since I haven't studied music myself.)

Comment: He did do this, by the way, several times. Notably, his concerto for four harpsichords and string orchestra is based on a Vivaldi concerto for four violins. Not that this helps us understand the joke.

Comment: Who knows? Perhaps there's a typo and it was supposed to be ***Change** for more voices* (alluding to the political ***Votes / voices for change*** which I think was a big thing for Obama).